# POST JSON object with enum id as number, response returns the enum string name instead of int id

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-5, asp.net5

Just wondering why when I send this JSON with a number `id`:

```
{
    "name": "yummy food",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "Indian",
            "id": "9",
            "iconCodePoint": 23145
        }
    ]
}
```

the field `Tags` gets stored in the database with a number id like this:

[image]

But the field `Tags` has the enum `string` name as the `id` field in the response:

```
{
    "name": "yummy food",
    "description": null,
    "image": null,
    "menuyItemRestaurants": null,
    "id": 7,
    "isNotVeganCount": 0,
    "isVeganCount": 0,
    "ratingsCount": 0,
    "rating": 0,
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": "Indian", <----------- HERE
            "iconCodePoint": 23145,
            "name": "Indian"
        }
    ],
    "establishments": null,
    "currentRevisionId": 0
}
```

the "class" version of the enum which adds more fields:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    public class MenuItemTag
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public MenuItemTag(string name, MenuItemTagEnum id, int iconCodePoint)
        {
            Id = id;
            IconCodePoint = iconCodePoint;
            Name = name;
        }

        public MenuItemTagEnum Id { get; set; }
        public int IconCodePoint { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The enum:

```
public enum MenuItemTagEnum
{
  Asian = 1,
  Barbecue,
  European,
  Bakery,
  Cafe,
  Deli,
  Desserts,
  FishAndChips,
  Indian,
  American,
  PubFood,
  Breakfast,
  Chinese,
  Fench,
  German,
  Japanese,
  Kebab,
  Mediterranian,
  LatinAmerican,
  MiddleEastern,
  Salad,
  Thai,
  Turkish,
  Vietnamese,
  Mexican,
  Sushi,
  Kiwi,
  Greek,
  HealthFood,
  Other,
  Korean,
  Italian
}
```

The database context which serializes the `MenuItem.Tags` field into one `string` table column :

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<MenuItemTag>()
        .Property(tag => tag.Id)
        .HasConversion<int>()
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    builder.Entity<MenuItemTag>().HasData(
        new MenuItemTag[] {
        new MenuItemTag(
            "American",
            MenuItemTagEnum.American,
            0xf803
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Asian",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Asian,
            0xf823
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Bakery",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Bakery,
            0xf705
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Barbecue",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Barbecue,
            0xf80f
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Breakfast",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Breakfast,
            0xe002
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Cafe",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Cafe,
            0xf6c5
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Chinese",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Chinese,
            0xf823
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Deli",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Deli,
            0xf81f
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Desserts",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Desserts,
            0xf551
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "European",
            MenuItemTagEnum.European,
            0xf7a2
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Fish & Chips",
            MenuItemTagEnum.FishAndChips,
            0xf7fe
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Indian",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Indian,
            0xf156
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "French",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Fench,
            0xf7f6
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "German",
            MenuItemTagEnum.German,
            0xf820
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Greek",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Greek,
            0xf68b
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Health Food",
            MenuItemTagEnum.HealthFood,
            0xf81e
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Italian",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Italian,
            0xf817
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Japanese",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Japanese,
            0xf56a
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Kebab",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Kebab,
            0xf821
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Kiwi",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Kiwi,
            0xf535
        ),
        new MenuItemTag(
            "Korean",
            MenuItemTagEnum.Korean,
            0xf159
    )});

    builder.Entity<MenuItem>()
    .Property(e => e.Tags)
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MenuItemTag>>(v, null),
        new ValueComparer<IList<MenuItemTag>>(
            (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
            c => (IList<MenuItemTag>)c.ToList()));
```

The controller:

```cs
// POST: api/MenuItems
// To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<MenuItem>> PostMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    _context.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetMenuItem", new { id = menuItem.Id }, menuItem);
}
```

Any Idea how I get my database converter for `MenuItem.Tags` to convert back to an `int` id to send in the JSON response instead of the string enum name?

I thought this code would do it:

```cs
builder.Entity<MenuItemTag>()
    .Property(tag => tag.Id)
    .HasConversion<int>()
    .ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easy set your own Conversion with

```
.HasConversion() => {
    set => Enum.GetName(typeof(<YourEnum>), set),
    get => {
      <your switch case>
    }
}
```

I have done that with an List in my current project.
I Wrote a little PoC of the "get Conversion function":
[Conversion Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO6sZ.png)
[Implementation Example/PoC Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQKg6.png)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show a switch case inside the `get` code block? My get case for `MenuItem` currently is `v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MenuItemTag>>(v, null),` and `MenuItemTag` is just `.HasConversion<int>()` so I assume the `.HasConversion<int>()` is the bit that needs a custom get

Comment: hello, at the beginning I gave you the solution how you can / should do it and you have already finished your code directly, only that you have to build the switch yourself, for that I wrote a switch with documentation in the 2nd example. this switch you can easy replace with "<your switch case>" there you should return the (Int32) <your enum member> instead of break, that was while i did this example quick and dirty in the main of the project where iam working atm.